# react with nginx on docker container - not loading App.tsx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a react application
when I run it locally its working with no issue using

```
npm run dev
```

I want to have my react app running locally and on aws with docker image
I created this docker image:

```
  # Step 1: Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:20.10.0 as build

# Step 2: Set the working directory in the container
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Step 3: Copy the package.json files and install dependencies
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm set audit false


# Step 4: Copy the rest of your app's source code
COPY . /app

# Step 5: Build your app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the application with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

# Step 6: Copy build artifacts from the 'build' stage to the Nginx directory
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Step 7: Expose port 80 for Nginx
EXPOSE 80

# Step 8: Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

config files for nginx x
nginx.conf

```
events {
    # Event-driven configuration
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Include server configurations
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # Further http configurations
}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 for incoming connections
    listen 80;

    # Define the root directory where your files are located
    # This should be the path to your built React application
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Specify the file to serve as index
    index index.html;

    # Handle Single Page Application (SPA) routing:
    # Attempt to serve any requested file or route, fall back to index.html if not found
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Custom error pages (optional)
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

the docker image is running with no errors:

```
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
2024/01/06 13:06:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:07:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 
NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:07:19 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02,\x01\x00\x02(\x03\x03\xF3P\xD9\xB0C\xB6\x9D1\x9D\x14\xE3\xBFz\x95\x1B\x22_\xFD8I\xA7\xE2\x16#DNy\x03\x5C\xED\x9F\x19 \xB61\xB2\x89C\xAA\xCA=\x8E\xA2\x18\x8B\x9Cs\x12f\x9C\xBD\xF9\x80J\xD2@eV;\xCA$i\xE8L\xDE\x00 \xFA\xFA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\xBF\xCA\xCA\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
    172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:07:19 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03-:\xE1\x8B/\xAA\xA0k^\xBC \xCF\xBA\x19\xF0\xFC\x18\xE5)r]\x9CZ42\xB3\xB7\xA3\xFB\x95`\x82 yL\xE0\x1DW[\x9ENwp\x97L\xC5\xE8[p6\xA6\xA7N^\xAB\xBE\xE8L\xD3\x0E\x83\x87 \xAD-\x00 jj\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93\xFA\xFA\x00\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
    172.17.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2024:13:07:19 +0000]
```

When i go to local host

I see the index.html file which located on public/html
[image]

But the issue is that its not loading the original tsx files

my index.html (on public dir)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="monetag" content="5a02f84c329734f784dc0af09b7ae775">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon192.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my nginx.conf ( on main directory)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

on this sdirectory i have plenty of files so i assume it copied them:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan  6 09:54 source-map-url
drwxr-xr-x   19 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 @webassemblyjs
drwxr-xr-x   24 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 @types
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 enhanced-resolve
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 loader-runner
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 infer-owner
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 webpack-sources
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 webpack
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 watchpack
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 tapable
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 serialize-javascript
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan  6 10:07 schema-utils
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1738 Jan  6 10:12 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        903386 Jan  6 10:12 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           201 Jan  6 10:37 vite.config.ts
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           758 Jan  6 11:36 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           398 Jan  6 11:50 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             4 Jan  6 11:52 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8181 Jan  6 11:52 index
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            41 Jan  6 11:52 ORIG_HEAD
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan  6 11:55 logs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           103 Jan  6 13:01 FETCH_HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           168 Jan  6 13:03 nginx.conf
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Where in the html does it load any js?

Comment: @DaveNewton only index.html

Comment: … I mean how does the browser get any JS delivered to it?

Comment: @DaveNewton browser no, only original index html, but docker container it has the App.abcd.js

Comment: … If you open an HTML file that never gets any JS it will never run the JS it doesn’t have. The index file (or wherever it’s supposed to be) needs to load/run/however your app works the JS of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Index.html was missing a section that not generated by Vite

```
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
```

And also remove this part

```
rollupOptions: {
  input: 'src/main.tsx' // This line should be removed or commented out
 }
```